# Flutter (Dart) round to nearest .5

Tags: flutter, dart

Actually what I was trying to acheive is round the nearest .5 double value like

```
var value1 = 23.2 // while rounding --> 23.0
var value2 = 23.6 // while rounding --> 23.5
var value3 = 23.8 // while rounding --> 24.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a function for it but you can simply use this function to get your rounded value:

```
double roundedValue(double value){
  return ((value * 2).round() / 2 ) ;
}
```

Example:

```
var value1 = 23.2 ; // while rounding --> 23.0
var value2 = 23.6 ;// while rounding --> 23.5
var value3 = 23.8 ; // while rounding --> 24.0
print(roundedValue(value1));
print(roundedValue(value2));
print(roundedValue(value3));
```